# What effects, if any, does your choice of gender have?

Tags: kingdoms-of-amalur-reckoning

After browsing through some of the Kingdoms of Amalur questions, I noticed that one achievement would have you wooing Rast Brattigan. Now, I imagine that Rast is receptive to wooing from either sex, as is often the case in video games when romance and achievements meet, but that got me wondering whether your choice of gender has any significant impact on your playthrough or not.

By significant, I mean something more substantial than references to your gender in dialogs. This is not unprecedented - Fallout 3 comes to mind, where your choice of gender would actually change the set of perks available to you (Black Widow vs. Lady Killer), and would in turn change the way you interact with male and female characters in the game world. The Mass Effect series is also a fine example, where specific romance options are only available to a specific gender.

So, just what does you gender affect when playing through Kingdoms of Amalur?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Liquid Seduction](http://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=3&ved=0CDgQFjAC&url=http://amalur.wikia.com/wiki/Alchemical_Recipes&ei=Pzo5T-P2Co6DsAK32piBAg&usg=AFQjCNHK7WSfa9QSxvt8tpIZsBa9ZOXRnQ) is a potion that you can find/create/buy that temporarily increases your Persuasion skill, but ONLY with NPCs of the opposite sex.

Besides that one item, the only differences I've noticed are all flavor in regards to how people speak to you and the context of certain quests (him vs. her, King vs. Queen, etc.).

Comment: In light of this revelation, I have no choice but to re-assign the accepted answer to you.

Comment: @Aubergine To be 100% fair I haven't actually USED the potion in question, but rather have discarded/sold every single one I've come across because I have too much gear already occupying my backpack slots.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think it makes any difference (other than my personal satisfaction at looking at a pretty female in cut scenes instead of ugly males)

If it did, I'm sure I would have gotten to be the Maiden instead of the heroic Knight who rescued his love in the [Reprisal Reprised](http://www.ign.com/wikis/kingdoms-of-amalur-reckoning/Reprisal_Reprised) quest. Or at very least that I wouldn't walk like a man.